# CollectionVew Edit Menu Not Coming Up

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

The Apple [documentation about doing CollectionViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html) says that the default behavior is for a long press to bring up the Edit Menu. It goes on to say that you must implement 3 delegate methods, and that's it.

I have a CollectionView that extends UICollectionViewController (and thus implements the data source delegate), and I implemented the delegates, but they are never being called. This CollectionView is setup in Interface Builder.

I dragged out a Long Tap Gesture Recognizer and made a method, and yes, it detects it, but that does me no good. According to the docs, the cell should detect the long tap and invoke the delegate.

The docs are really lame on this, which is too bad. CollectionViews are great, but seriously, this just does not work as advertised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement all, please check UICollectionView.h in UIKit.framework

// These methods provide support for copy/paste actions on cells.
// All three should be implemented if any are.

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender{
return YES;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender{
//your action
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as my original post said, I did implement all three methods.

Comment: Correction, I'm an idiot: I tried to get the delegate methods through code completion, but they didn't come up and when I copied/pasted them from the docs, they did not have the collection view param. Thanks.

Comment: Dude, as I said: the method signatures were not exact matches, everything worked once I added the sections of each that were missing from the docs [:(UICollectionView *)collectionView]. Thanks.